# Is there a way to reset click event data from a htmlwidget inside of a shiny application?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, onclick, htmlwidgets

I have a custom htmlwidget embedded in a Shiny application that sends data about a position on the widget whenever the user clicks on a region in the widget. I want to add a "reset"-style button to stop data from being sent from the widget to the shiny application whenever the user clicks this reset button. The data sent from the widget triggered from a click event is used to filter a data table in the shiny application.

In the `renderValue` method of the htmlwidget there is a configuration javascript object which has a callback function that is invoked when clicking on regions:

```
  // inside htmlwidget JS render function
  HTMLWidgets.widget({
    name: widget,
    type: output,
    factory: function(el, width, height) {
      return {
        renderValue: function() {
          var configuration = {
                   ...
              onDrawShapes: function() {
                var shapes = document.getElementsByClassName("shapes");
                for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                shapes[i].onclick = function(ev){
                 Shiny.onInputChange("selectedReg", this.__data__);
            }
          }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Then in the Shiny app I have a filtering function of the UI:

```
# server function in shiny app
 server <- function(input, output, session) {
     ...
     # reactive expr region filtering
     reg_filter <- reactive({
       if (!is.null(input$chosenReg$pos)) {
         table_data() %>%
            filter(POS==input$selectedReg$pos)
       } else {
          table_data()
      })
      
output$table <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(
      reg_filter()  
     })
  }
```